# how to convert image from rgb to grayscale in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I'm working with tensorflow lite model and flutter, where the model receive grayscale image as an input. is there any way to convert RGB Image to Grayscale image using flutter?

Comment: Please notice that converting between image formats is not an `artificial-intelligence` issue (tag removed).

Answer (score -1):

The ColorFiltered widget can help. Please note that this will effect transparent pixels as well.

```
ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
      Colors.grey,
      BlendMode.saturation,
    ),
  child: Your Image Here),
)
```